# Python, Tensorflow: Random Shuffle Queue Error (insufficient elements) while experimenting with "Tensorflow for Machine Learning"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am running the code found on this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/backstopmedia/tensorflowbook/blob/master/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/softmax.py).
Unfortunately, it always stops with an error, namely:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 49)
 [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/M99E374/Projects/Training/tensorflowbook-master/tensorflowbook-master/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/softmax.py", line 93, in <module>
print("loss: ", sess.run([total_loss]))
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 766, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 964, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 49)
 [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'shuffle_batch', defined at:
  File "C:/Users/M99E374/Projects/Training/tensorflowbook-master/tensorflowbook-master/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/softmax.py", line 79, in <module>
X, Y = inputs()
  File "C:/Users/M99E374/Projects/Training/tensorflowbook-master/tensorflowbook-master/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/softmax.py", line 46, in inputs
read_csv(100, "iris.data", [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [""]])
  File "C:/Users/M99E374/Projects/Training/tensorflowbook-master/tensorflowbook-master/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/softmax.py", line 40, in read_csv
min_after_dequeue=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 917, in shuffle_batch
dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 458, in dequeue_many
self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1099, in _queue_dequeue_many
timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\M99E374\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 49)
 [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

Anybody, who knows how to solve this issue?

Sidenote1: I have the iris.data dataset from [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/) and it has 150 rows.

Sidenote2: I run Python 3.5 and just downloaded Tensorflow today

Sidenote3: Don't forget to change the print statement to a function statement.

Comment: Usually this kind of error is caused by an exception in another thread (usually an input processing thread), which should also be printed out in the logs. When one of these threads crashes, it will signal the rest of the computation to shut down by closing the input queues, which in turn triggers the exception that you're seeing there. Are there any other stack traces in the output?

Comment: @mrry : I added all the traceback. Is the code working for you?

Comment: Hmm, all the exceptions there appear to be for the same op. Either there is an additional traceback above what you posted in the log, or the error is more mysterious than I expected :). Looking at the code and the fact you're on Windows, perhaps [this filename processing line](https://github.com/backstopmedia/tensorflowbook/blob/cbe987a93f5ef95ab88405fd53c9fdfdd528bf0d/chapters/04_machine_learning_basics/softmax.py#L26) is wrong? Try printing out the filename it computes and see if it matches an actual file.